# Como faço parar deixar dois botões de rádio, um do lado do outro usando Angular e IONIC 3

Tags: angularjs, mobile, ionic3

Estou com dúvidas de como deixar botões de rádio ao lado outro. Conseguindo fazer isso normalmente, porém estou tendo problemas por causa do radio-group

```
            <ion-list radio-group>
            <ion-col>
                <ion-item>
                <ion-label>PF</ion-label>
                <ion-radio checked="true" (click)="selectIndividuo('1')"></ion-radio>
                </ion-item>
            </ion-col>

            <ion-col >
                <ion-item>
                <ion-label>PJ</ion-label>
                <ion-radio (click)="selectIndividuo('2')"></ion-radio>
                </ion-item>

            </ion-col>
            </ion-list>

        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para colocar em horizontal remova ion-list e tente assim:

```
  <ion-row radio-group>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>PF</ion-label>
        <ion-radio ></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-item>
       <ion-label>PJ</ion-label>
        <ion-radio></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```

[Exemplo stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/radio-button-horizontal)

Comment: deu certo!!!! tnks sooo much!!! ;)